# Почему символы в адресной строке у переменной в виде html кода

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня переменные в адресной строке почему то выглядят в виде его html кода, такие как запятая, точка с запятой, кавычки и т.д. Т.е. если я передаю у переменной fsize значение 52;54, то они выглядят вот так.

```
?fsize=52%3B54
```

От чего это зависит? Как можно сделать в нормальном виде? Такая же ерунда с со всеми символами ... Хотя вижу на сайтах где все нормально отображается

```
?sort=popular&price=6800;11200&size=58;46;44
```

Answer (score 1):

Для преобразования url-строки используейте `url decode`.